# C++: Iterator error only for one of two identical cases

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I'm looping over (almost) the same string object in exactly the same way, using iterators, and the second one keeps returning an error. I feel really stupid, am I missing something?

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Sentence
{
  string text;
  Sentence(const string& text)
      : text{text}
  {
    for (string::const_iterator it = text.cbegin(); it != text.cend(); ++it)
    {
      // Actions: WORKS FINE:
    }
  }

  string str() const
  {
    for (string::const_iterator it = text.cbegin(); it != text.cend(); ++it)
    {
      // Actions: RETURNS ERROR: Process finished with exit code 132 (interrupted by signal 4: SIGILL)
    }
  }
};

int main()
{
  vector<Sentence> vec;
  vec.push_back(Sentence{""});
  vec[0].str();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if you remove the `vector`?

Comment: BTW: The compiler would tell you what's wrong if you enabled warnings.

Comment: The debugger throws the following:
EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  string str() const
```

As you can see here, your `str()` is declared as returning a `std::string`, but the actual code does not `return` anything.

This is called "undefined behavior", and you cannot expect any meaningful results from this point on.

You will need to fix this `str()` method so they its either declared as returning a `void`, or actually returns a `std::string`, correctly.

All modern C++ compilers will issue a warning or a diagnostic message about this common bug. If your compiler produced a warning message when you compiled your code, this would be an example of not ignoring ***any*** kind of messages from your compiler. If you did not get any message from your compiler, check its settings and command-line options, and turn on all warning messages, or upgrade your compiler.

Comment: Ok. It was indeed something stupid... got lost in details and forgot the basics :D. Thanks a lot Sam.